# expand unix variable inside sed command

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need to replace current value in configuration file with new value which is assigned to variable ,

like

```
file_name=abc.txt
```

needs to be replaced like

```
file_name=xyz.txt
```

where `$file=xyz.txt`

I tried

```
sed -i 's/file_name=.*/file_name=$file/g'  conf_file.conf
```

however the variable is not getting expanded,
it comes like  `file_name=$file`.

any pointers?

Comment: i tried with above duplicate thread but in my case it shoudl search for 'file_name= ' and then replace with 'file_name=xyz.txt'

Comment: The duplicates say to use double quotes not single quotes. If you tried that it would work.

Answer (score 3):

This should work,assuming that variable `file` has value:`xyz.txt` assigned to it:

```
sed "s/file_name=.*/file_name=${file}/g" file_name
```

Output:

`file_name=xyz.txt`

Comment: But this will not work if `$file` has spaces in it. Why have you used `${file}` outside the double quotes? That's not necessary, and makes it wrong if the variable contains whitespace.

Comment: That's right..Thanks @JonathanWakely for the suggestion..i think it should work with my edited answer.I've removed double quotes `" "` from the `${file}`

Comment: its not working tried with      .........    sed "s/$$file_name=.*/$$file_name=${file}/g" file_name

Comment: Why have you added `$$`? That will give you the process ID of your current shell, which is not what you want. Why don't you try what people have actually suggested, instead of trying something else that doesn't work?

Comment: actually in my config file the file_name will be as $$file_name, so tried with that, its informatica config file, where parameters will be given by $$parameter_name

Comment: Please edit your question based on your actual issue, also please let us know how you are defining the variable `file`?